# Rendering SurfaceView - canvas clearsup on touch

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

I'm new to the game development in Android. This is what I'm trying to do

- Render a background (green field) with items (items are behind the background but I've made them appear at the top for now)
- Drawing an additional image (dig hole) on touch
- Doing a collision test to see if user has found the item

I'm stuck with the second step as I'm not able to get it working at all. Blank screen appears as soon as touch event method invoked. Only a dig hole image is drawn on the blank screen. I've read thru the documents but couldn't figure out what's going wrong here.

Here is my code

```
class DrawSurface extends android.view.SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, View.OnTouchListener {
Bitmap mBMPField;
Bitmap mBMPHole;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
float x = 0;
float y = 0;
boolean touched = false;

public DrawSurface(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public DrawSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet) {
    super(context, attrSet);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public DrawSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet, int styleAttr) {
    super(context, attrSet, styleAttr);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i("a", "Inside surfaceCreated");
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    mBMPField = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.field);
    mBMPHole = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.hole);
    surfaceHolder = holder;
    Canvas canvas = null;
    try {
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), String.valueOf(canvas.hashCode()));
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBMPField, 0, 0, null);
        Paint paintText = new Paint();
        paintText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paintText.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintText.setTextSize(20);
        ArrayList<Item> mItems = loadItems();
        for (Item item : mItems) {
            item.setX((int) (Math.random() * this.getWidth()));
            item.setY((int) (Math.random() * this.getHeight()));
            canvas.drawText(item.getText(), item.getX(), item.getY(), paintText);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if(canvas!=null) {
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.i("a", "Inside onTouch");
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            touched = true;
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), String.valueOf(canvas.hashCode()));
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBMPHole, x - mBMPHole.getWidth() / 2, y - mBMPHole.getHeight() / 2, null);
            }
            finally {
                if(canvas!=null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private class Item {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private String text;
    private boolean found;

    public boolean isFound() {
        return found;
    }

    public void setFound(boolean found) {
        this.found = found;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}

private ArrayList<Item> loadItems()
{
    InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.items);
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    String line;

    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setText(line);
            items.add(item);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Reading list of Items failed!", e);
    }
    finally {
        try
        {
            if (reader != null) reader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error closing file reader.", e);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

}

Any advice would greatly helpful here